# Error getting server certificate generating datasnap client classes

Tags: https, datasnap

I have a datasnap server configured for HTTPS, this starts and runs fine as far as I can tell.

From the client's point of view when I 'Generate datasnap client classes' via the TSQLConnection component I get an error message - Error getting server certificate.

Can anybody offer any useful info regarding this and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a bug with the TDSCertfiles component in the Server project.

Having set the following properties programmatically, the bug seems to ignore what I have put in code and looks for what is set manually in the object inspector (empty) :

- Cerfile
- Keyfile
- RootCertfile

FIX - After setting the above properties and before calling **DSHTTPService.Start** add the following :

**DSCertFiles.SetServerProperties(DSHTTPService.HttpServer)**.

Retesting the connection/Generating server methods from my client app, I no longer get the error message and it successfully connects.